# jQuery: Multiple Values - Dropdown Menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is this the correct way to pass two ids in jQuery?

I am having the following issue as seen in the image.

Domain Registration: Doesn't show input box.

Domain Transfer: Only shows one input box.

**Image:**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
#domainToBeReged, #domainToBeReged0, #domainToBeTransfered{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="domainRequired">Domain Registration: </label>
                    <select name="domainRequired" id="domainRequired">
                        <option value="pleaseSelect">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
        <div id="domainToBeReged">
            <label for="domainToBeReged">Domain One:</label><input name="domainToBeReged" id="domainToBeReged" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
            <label for="domainToBeReged0">Domain Two:</label><input name="domainToBeReged0" id="domainToBeReged0" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />

        </div>
        <label for="domainTransfer">Domain Transfer: </label>
                    <select name="domainTransfer" id="domainTransfer">
                        <option value="pleaseSelect">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
        <div id="domainToBeTransfered">
                    <label for="domainToBeTransfered">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeTransfered" id="domainToBeTransfered" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
                  <label for="domainToBeTransfered0">Domain:</label><input name="domainToBeTransfered0" id="domainToBeTransfered0" type="text" placeholder="http://www." />
        </div>
        <label for="currentHosting">Current Hosting: </label>
        <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="currentHosting" id="currentHosting"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="nextButton" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
$('select[name="domainRequired"]').change(function() {
            var $domain = $('#domainToBeReged','#domainToBeReged0');
                if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
                    $domain.show();
                } else {
                    $domain.hide(); 
        }
            });             


        $('select[name="domainTransfer"]').change(function() {
            var $domain = $('#domainToBeTransfered');
                if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
                    $domain.show();
                } else {
                    $domain.hide(); 
        }
            });             

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not completely correct:

- `$("selector1", "selector2")` is searching for `selector1` inside `selector2`. It's basically equivalent to `$("selector2").find("selector1")`. You seem to just want two independent selectors. Use the *comma selector* instead.
- You can use `.toggle(bool)` to eliminate the `if` and `show`/`hide`.

```
$("#domainToBeReged, #domainToBeReged0").toggle($(this).val() === "yes");
```

Answer (score 1):

No your jquery must be:

```
$('#domainToBeReged,#domainToBeReged0');
```